# jQuery does not adjust scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Basically, I want to have certain points on my website, that act like "magnets". If you are near one of these, the window should scroll to the top, similar to this jQuery plug-in : http://benoit.pointet.info/stuff/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin/

The problem is, that the window does not scroll, even though the page is in range of a "magnet".

here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

var magnets = [];
var range = 200;
var active = true;

 $('.container').each(function(i,obj) {
    magnets.push($(this).offset().top);
});

console.log(magnets);

var attract = function(where,time){
    $('html, body').animate({ 
        scrollTop: where
    }, time);
    active = false;
};

//checks the range of a magnet
var magnetic = function(what){
    var top = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    var min = top - range;
    var max = top + range;

    if( (min <= what) && (max >= what) ){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}

//returns, wether you are in range of a magnet from your magnets array or not
var inRange = function(){
    var magnet = -1;

    for(var i=0; i<magnets.length; i++){
        if( magnetic(magnets[i]) == true){
            magnet = i;
        }
    }
    return magnet;
}

$(window).scroll(function() {

    $('.counter').html("");

    $('.counter').append("<p>"+inRange()+"</p>");

    if(active == true && inRange != -1){
        attract(magnets[inRange()]);
    }
    else if(active == false && inRange() == -1){
        active = true;
    }
    else if(active == true && inRange() == -1){
        console.log("fuck");
    }
});
});
```

alternative codepen link: http://codepen.io/NiclasvanEyk/pen/jEMrZr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your code:

```
if(active == true && inRange != -1){
    attract(magnets[inRange()]);
}
```

Should be

```
if(active == true && inRange() != -1){
    attract(magnets[inRange()]);
}
```